# How to random int[] images without repeating in bindviewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a problem that I want to random an image array in Recyclerview onBindViewHolder, everything is working fine but it is repeating random images from the array like 2 images coming 2 times. i am using it in vertical recyclerview for showing text and images to their exact position Like if i have 2 array one is string and the other one is int for images, so i want both array position will random simultaneously at same position but without duplicates my code is doing everything perfectly but its repeating the images.

**This is my full code**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewwHolder>  {
     private int [] arraylist;
    private Context ctx;
   private ImageView name;
    private TextView textView;
   private   String [] text ;



    public MyAdapter(int[] arraylist, String []text,Context ctx) {
        this.arraylist = arraylist;
        this.text = text;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewwHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(ctx.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,  viewGroup, false) ;
        return new ViewwHolder(view);    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewwHolder viewwHolder, final int i) {



        Random random=new Random();
      final int po=random.nextInt(arraylist.length);
        name.setImageResource(arraylist[po]);
        textView.setText(text[po]);

        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent= new Intent(ctx, second.class);
                           intent.putExtra("imageposition", arraylist[po]);
                           intent.putExtra("textposition",text[po]);
                           ctx.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arraylist.length;
    }


    public class ViewwHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewwHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemoneimageone);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Why you don't remove from the list the item that you don't want to me randomized anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the image from the list after it has been used.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> arraylist; // use a dynamic array.


final int po = random.nextInt(arraylist.size());
int imageResource = arraylist.get(po);
arraylist.remove(po); // if you don't want to lose it, you can store it in another ArrayList before removal
name.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Comment: but where is my int [] variable name arraylist, it has array of images. thanks for helping but it didn't works

Comment: Use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the images to repeat, then you don't want to randomly select an image at each call to `onBindViewHolder`. Instead, you want to shuffle the images (and associated texts) once and go through the shuffled array(s) in order. Since you have both an image array and a text array (and presumably need to keep them in sync) I recommend creating an array of integers from 0 through `arraylist.length-1` and then shuffling that. (You can find code to shuffle an `int[]` in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1519736/535871).) You would do this outside of `onBindViewHolder` and store the shuffled indexes in a member field (let's call it `shuffledArray`). Then instead of

```
final int po=random.nextInt(arraylist.length);
```

use

```
final int po = shuffledArray[i];
```

An alternative (better, in my view) would be to create an array of image/text pairs and store it in an `ArrayList` of an appropriate type. You can then shuffle the list using `Collections.shuffle`. Once again, this would be done once outside of `onBindViewHolder`.

For some reason, Java has a `Collections.shuffle` method but doesn't have an `Arrays.shuffle` method.

EDIT: Now that I see your entire class, here's how I would change it:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewwHolder>  {
    ...

    private int[] shuffled;

    public MyAdapter(int[] arraylist, String []text,Context ctx) {
        this.arraylist = arraylist;
        this.text = text;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        shuffled = new int[arraylist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) shuffled[i] = i;
        shuffle(shuffled);
    }

    private static void shuffle(int[] array) {
        Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          int tmp = array[index];
          array[index] = array[i];
          array[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, as before, inside `onBindViewHolder`, change the way you set `po` to:

```
final int po = shuffled[i];
```

Everything else can remain the same.

Comment: hey updated my full code can u please help me now, because i think u didnt understood my problem.